# Прописная или строчная после угловых скобок?

Tags: цитата

В справочнике Мильчина есть пункт о многоточии в угловых скобках при пропуске в цитате одного или нескольких предложений:

Полное предложение цитаты. <...> Полное предложение цитаты.

Предложение цитаты с опущенными в конце словами (последним словом)... <...> ...Предложение цитаты с опущенными начальными словами (первым словом).

Вопрос: означает ли это, что если опущено начальное слово (начальные слова) в предложении цитаты, которое идет за пропущенным предложением (пропущенными предложениями), то слово, идущее за пропущенным словом (пропущенными словами) -- за угловыми скобками -- должно писаться с прописной буквы?

Сначала мой дед ремонтировал часы и всякую хозяйственную утварь. Потом занимался типографским делом. Был чем-то вроде метранпажа. А через два года приобрел закусочную на Светланке.

После сокращения этой цитаты:

1. Сначала мой дед ремонтировал часы... <...> ...через два года приобрел закусочную на Светланке.
2. Сначала мой дед ремонтировал часы... <...> ...Через два года приобрел закусочную на Светланке.

Какой из этих двух вариантов правильный?

Comment: Как-то раз батарея участвовала в штурме. Мой дед побежал в атаку. Орудийный расчет должен был поддержать атакующих. Но орудия молчали. Как выяснилось, спина моего деда заслонила неприятельские укрепления.

Comment: Как-то раз батарея участвовала в штурме. <...> ...Спина моего деда заслонила неприятельские укрепления.

Comment: Как-то раз батарея участвовала в штурме. <...> ...спина моего деда заслонила неприятельские укрепления.

Comment: Из Мильчина мне непонятно, с какой буквы писать слово "спина" -- с прописной или строчной.

Comment: Здесь - с заглавной. Хоть по Мильчину, хоть по здравому смыслу. Первое предложение закончилось точкой. Новое предложение, даже неполное - с заглавной.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос интересный. Другими словами, вас интересует цитата, в которой опущенная часть относится к разным предложением - и соответственно куски цитируемого  текста тоже относятся к двум разным предложениям. Но при этом сохранившийся текст в цитате представляет собой одно связанное предложение.
Мне кажется, случай не оговорен специально ни у Мильчина, ни где еще.

Чисто внешне строчная буква во второй части (после уголкового отточия) тут смотрится много лучше. Но у Мильчина нет даже намека на изъятия из общего правила. Поэтому, боюсь, что именно второй вариант, с прописной, следует признать правильным "по Мильчину".

А не могли бы вы какой другой пример подобрать, этот уж больно натянутым выглядит. Во второй части опушен всего лишь один союз (а почему бы не процитировать с ним?) да и смысл несколько искажается. У Довлатова говорится "через два года занятий **типографским делом**". А при цитировании получается, что "через два года **ремонта часов**".

Answer (score 1):

Цитату начинают с прописной (большой) буквы в следующих случаях:

Когда цитирующий начинает цитатой предложение, даже если в цитате опущены начальные слова и она открывается многоточием.

А. Э. Мильчин, Л. К. Чельцова. Справочник издателя и автора. М., 2003.

### Дополнение.

Если в конце абзаца многоабзацной цитаты опущены слова, такой абзац заканчивается многоточием, а если при этом в начале следующего абзаца опущены слова (первое слово), то он начинается многоточием. ***Структура текста цитаты не меняется: она делится на абзацы так же, как в источнике. Напр.:***

**Первый абзац цитаты с опущенными в конце словами...
...Второй абзац цитаты с опущенным начальным словом или начальными словами.**

Т.е. если цитатой начинается новый абзац, то опираясь на вышеприведенное правило, должна писаться прописная буква.